# MediaCapture error code 20 in iOS emulator

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I've been trying to use the ionics MediaCapture api to record a video. So far I couldn't make it work. All I get is the `{"code":20}` error, that is printed in the `catch` for the `captureVideo` function.

This is my code:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })

    export class HomePage {

      plat: Platform;

      constructor(platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, private mediaCapture: MediaCapture) {
        this.plat = platform;
      }

      startRecording() {
        let _self = this;
        let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 3 };
        this.plat.ready().then(() => {
          _self.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options)
            .then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
              console.log(data)
            }).catch((err: CaptureError) => {
              console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
      }
    }
```

I run it using `ionic cordova emulate ios -l -c`, which opens an iOS emulator with iOS v11.2. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Comment: @robenrajan Yes, this need to be tested by making a build and running it on a device. No emulator/ionic devapp will make it work.